# Completely remove one item from a list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list like this:

```
MyList = [1,2,3,4,5,'hi', 6,7, 'hi', 8, 'hi', 9]
```

how can I remove all the items 'hi' from the list? I have tried the method remove() but it works only once:

```
MyList.remove('hi')
>>>> MyList
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'hi',8,'hi',9]
```

Yes, I could do something like this:

```
while 'hi' in MyList:
    MyList.remove('hi')
```

but does anyone know any more elegant way than iterating n-times the same instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
MyList = [v for v in MyList if v != 'hi']
```

This rebuilds the list to only contain values not equal to `'hi'`.

`list.remove()` calls must move the rest of the list items forward, using a list comprehension instead is more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

`while 'hi' in MyList: MyList.remove('hi')` is `O(N**2)`, better use a simple list comprehension which does the same thing in `O(N)` time:

```
MyList = [item for item in MyList if item != 'hi']
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out, that's why I wanted something different. Despite my very limited knowledge of Python, does not list comprehension iterate O(N**2) anyway?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ No, a LC is `O(N)`, you're iterating over the list only once.

Comment: @Aswhini Chaudhary, true. I will use list comprehension then, thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set two answers accepted, for sake of correctness I will accept Martjin's one cause it came slightly before and it's exactly the same. Thanks a lot for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter function I guess.
Here is docs: [filter docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
MyList = [1,2,3,4,5,'hi', 6,7, 'hi', 8, 'hi', 9]

def f(item, element="hi"):
    if item == element:
        return False
    else:
        return True

print filter(f, MyList)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Thanks to Tim Pietzcker for his improvement.
The f function could be shorter

```
def f(item, element="hi"): return item != element
```

Comment: +1 for `filter()`, -1 for your function which should read `def f(item, element="hi"): return item != element`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also use generator expression:

```
NewList = (x for x in MyList if x != 'hi')
```

Then you can iterate this as `NewList.next()` until it raise StopIteration.

Comment: "not x == 'hi'" instead of "x != 'hi'" ? I would suggest the latter.

Comment: @Paddy3118 Can you tell me the reason why shouldn't i use "not x == 'hi'" ?

Comment: Hi @Manjunath, It is purely a subjective stylistic issue. Do you say "This is False" or "This is not True"? In "not x == 'hi'" there are two tests to read: not and equal; in the second case of "x != 'hi'" just the one: not-equal. The second seems to more directly impart its meaning.

Comment: @Manjunath `!=` is clearly more readable, succinct than `not x == ...` and does the same thing in less byte code steps. And in case `x` was an instance of some user defined class then it would've called `__eq__` instead of `__ne__`, and note that it is not compulsory to have `__ne__` == `not __ne__` in user defined classes.

Comment: @Manjunath And this is applicable to `in` and `is` operator as well: `x not in foo` should be preferred over `not x in foo`, though these two compile to same byte code but internally Python's peephole optimizer actually converts the second expression to the first one.

Comment: * `__ne__ == not __eq__`